# iPad simulator multitouch input?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

Does the iPad simulator support multitouch input (3 or more fingers)?

Answer (score 14):

Not on a default setup (you can do two fingers by holding down opt/shift, but not three). There are some third party tools that will let you do this (http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/).

As a general rule, you should be testing on hardware where possible, because there are some pretty big differences between simulator and device.